# ubuntu live-server as rescue system - how do i log in?

Tags: server, 20.04, password, users

i want to try out a few things on the ubuntu live-server (currently `ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso` from https://releases.ubuntu.com/).

it would be much easier for me to be able to log into that live system over ssh. i could also imagine using that as a rescue system in the future (yes, there may be better options for that).

i was looking around on the system a bit (`# cat /etc/shadow`) and found that the only (pre-installed) user that has a password set is `installer`.

what is this user's password? (if that is public it should be somewhere in the docs but i could not find it so far...)

Answer (score 1):

on the installer screen you can go to `Help` -> `Help on SSH access` and the password will be displayed.

the `cloud-init` service on the live-server sets a random password for the `installer` user at boot. it can be found in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
ubuntu-server cloud-init [...] Set the following 'random' passwords
ubuntu-server cloud-init [...] installer:S0m3R4ndomPassw0rd
```

---

as `cloud-init` is running you can always provide a `users:` section in your datasource and configure a user.

---

in earlier versions is seems to have been possible to pass `ubuntu-user:password` as a kernel option (i can't find the reference to that now...). i tried that with `installe-user:password` - with the effect that the installer failed to setup the `installer` user

originally found on the discussion here: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/interactive-live-server-installation-on-ibm-z-vm-s390x/16604